# How do I detect if the same directory was clicked twice in a list?

Tags: java, android, list, ftp

I made an FTP/FileBrowser Activity that lets the user single click on a directory to navigate into it, however I want to make a double click necessary because the list is a multi-select for mass delete, download etc. I created an int var called remclickcount that implements++ every time a list item is clicked, however if you click Directory A twice it works fine. However if you click Directory A then click Directory B it navigates to Directory B. How can I count the clicks for a single directory?

```
remote.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                r_itla.setSelectedPosition(position);
                String selectedFile = r_directoryEntries.get(position)
                        .getText();
                boolean isDirectory = map.get(selectedFile).booleanValue();
                if (isDirectory){
                    remclickcount++;
                    if(remclickcount==2) {

                    r_directoryEntries.clear();
                    r_itla.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    ftpPrintFilesList(selectedFile);
                    try {
                        FTPHelper.mFTPClient
                                .changeWorkingDirectory(selectedFile.toString());
                        remclickcount=0;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
                } else if (!isDirectory) {
                    // Toast.makeText(FTPConnector.this, selectedFile,
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    currentRemoteFile = selectedFile;
                }

            }
        });
```

Working code:

```
remote.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                r_itla.setSelectedPosition(position);
                String selectedFile = r_directoryEntries.get(position)
                        .getText();
                boolean isDirectory = map.get(selectedFile).booleanValue();
                if (isDirectory){
                    if(selectedFile.equals(lastClickSelectedFile)) {

                    r_directoryEntries.clear();
                    r_itla.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    ftpPrintFilesList(selectedFile);
                    try {
                        FTPHelper.mFTPClient
                                .changeWorkingDirectory(selectedFile.toString());

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }else if(!selectedFile.equals(lastClickSelectedFile)){
                        lastClickSelectedFile = selectedFile;
                    }
                } else if (!isDirectory) {
                    // Toast.makeText(FTPConnector.this, selectedFile,
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    currentRemoteFile = selectedFile;
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I assume that if the user clicks on directory A, then on directory B, then directory A, that *doesn't* count as a double-click?  If that's correct, then you don't really want to count the clicks for each file.  What I'd do is to define a private String member in your class, `lastClickSelectedFile`.  Then, if they click on a directory: if `selectedFile.equals(lastClickSelectedFile)`, then the user has double-clicked.  Otherwise, set `lastClickSelectedFile = selectedFile` and don't take any action.  If the user clicks on something else, set `lastClickSelectedFile = null`.  If that doesn't give you quite the behavior you're looking for, please clarify.

Comment: Ahh thank you thats it. It's late and I'll try it tomorrow and post my fixed code but this makes perfect sense